# Email addresses in body of MS Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

In MS Outlook, if I type the following in the **BODY** of the email

me@you.com    outlook will assume this is an email address and put a mailto: around  it

but if I type

that'sMyDog@you.com    outlook will treat this as text. Is there a setting in outlook to escape single quotes or anything that will make a name like O'brien work the same as Obrien?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook uses angle brackets to force a URL, e.g.

```
<www.example.com/address containing spaces>
```

However even this does not seem to work for apostrophes in email addresses. What you need to do is escape the apostrophe: the hex for `'` is hex 27 so it can be escaped as:

```
<that%27sMyDog@you.com>
```

If you are doing this programmatically or not, if so there should be a URL encode type function available in the language you are using that will do this for you.

Comment: Thank you Paul.   Any idea why I get -1 for asking a question? I'm thankful for the help on this site, but when idiots give a -1 for asking a question it makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: @Rich: I think the problem in this case is the question did not appear to be programming related. This is also why your euestion was closed as 'off topic'. Also check out the sister site [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), where this question may have had better reception (though no guarantees that it wouldn't have been closed there too).